# check if a page is accessed from address bar or from submitted form

Tags: php, codeigniter

Just like the question title, if I have an update_process.php, how to check if people access it by typing it in the address bar or if they go through the page from submitted form?

So if they type it in the address bar, I'll redirect them to other pages.

Oh yeah, i'm talking about the method in CI. so maybe if the file is blog.php and method update_process, i don't want people to type in the address bar blog/update_process

Comment: Check the referrer, if it's empty, then they *probably* typed the page in the address bar.  This isn't fool proof though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the $_SERVER global variable

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

If not set to POST, then they did not use the form

Answer (score 0):

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct access allowed');

Comment: duh, completely forgot about the first line in most files in CI. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field inside your form and in your update_process.php check to see if this exists (`$_POST['<field>'] or $_GET['<field>']`).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //or GET
{
//form
}
else
{
//url
}
```